# Chart js with problems when using too many series

Tags: charts, chart.js, angular-chart

I am using angular chart in one application which basically makes use of chart js. The version of chart js I am using at the moment is the 2.4.0, with angular chart version 1.1.1 (the current lastest one). 
So, when I insert few series (for example 4) everything works fine. The problem is when I have cases that handle with 10 series at a time. The event of clicking the serie in order to hide it block somehow and this error is displayed in console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'clearRect' of null
at Object.helpers.clear (Chart.js:5880)
at Chart.Controller.clear (Chart.js:4072)
at Chart.Controller.draw (Chart.js:4365)
at ChartElement.animation.render (Chart.js:4345)
at Object.startDigest (Chart.js:3672)
at Chart.js:3645
```

To try to help you I moved to the line the error is occuring in Chart.js file:

```
// -- Canvas methods
helpers.clear = function(chart) {
    chart.ctx.clearRect(0, 0, chart.width, chart.height);
};
```

Have anyone already got this problem? Does Chart js doesn't handle to many series?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This was happening to me when I ran out of colors to use for my series. Once I fixed that the hiding and showing of series worked fine, plus no more errors.